# How to create a mysql user that can access from any host but localhost

Tags: mysql, users

I was asked to create a mysql user that can connect to the server from any host but localhost.

I tend to believe that "%" also means localhost but according to my teacher, localhost is not part of "%" and that `CREATE USER user@"%";`  should do the job but my tests proof otherwise.

[image]

The only solution that I've found to solve the problem is with `CREATE USER user@localhost ACCOUNT LOCK;`

Can anybody educate me about this?

Answer (score 0):

It is "standard practice" to provide a bogus connection with minimal or no permissions, then let a wildcard let others in from other places.

This might suffice:

```
CREATE USER user@localhost IDENTIFIED BY "I'm not going to tell you the pwd";
```

Or maybe

```
CREATE USER user@localhost;
GRANT usage TO user@localhost;
```

but no other grant.

Here's the logic:  `user@localhost` is more specific than `user@"%"`, so, when `user` logs in through `localhost`, the bogus connection will rule.  Coming from some IP address or hostname, will go through the wildcard.

Comment: So, you're saying that in addition to issuing `CREATE USER` and `GRANT USAGE` to `user@localhost`, you should have `GRANT long, list, of, privileges TO user@"%"`?

Comment: @Vérace-getVACCINATEDNOW - No.  The Grants for user `blah` that only needs to access database `Blah` "should" go like:  `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON Blah.* TO blah@"%";`  For security reasons, only `root` (or equivalent) should use `ON *.*`.

Comment: Ah, you mean privileges per schema/database? Thanks!

Comment: Privileges can be for all / database / table / column.  By database is usually good both for limiting a login and for easily providing all (or nearly all) that is really needed for that login.